# How to create an sqlite view to be used with Room?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am trying to migrate my database over to use Android's Room Architecture. However I have some complex sqlite View's in my application. I don't see any information or documentation on how to create a view with room. Can anyone give me examples or point to tutorials?

Comment: what do you mean sqlite views, can you give an example what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think that this tutorial by Florina Muntenescu, developer advocate at Google can help you a bit: https://medium.com/google-developers/7-steps-to-room-27a5fe5f99b2

Answer (score 3):

You can use `androidx.room.DatabaseView` annotation

Example from documentation:

```
   @DatabaseView("SELECT id, last_name FROM User")
   public class UserSummary {
       public long id;
        @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
       public String lastName;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A view in sql is just a live updating query. Using LiveData you can get the live updates, and you can simply create a new entity to use specifically for your view. This class will hold all the data your view will. Then in your entities DAO you paste your sql query associated with the view.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67033276) in Android Room to support Database Views in the state of `Fixed`, perhaps waiting for creators to support it would be a good call.

although using a hacky method you might get it done:

You may create an @Entity similar to your view (in columns) then onCreate of the database drop the table generated for this Entity.

```
Room
    .databaseBuilder(context, DueDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
    .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
          super.onCreate(db);
          //Drop the fake table and create a view with the same name
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE view_name");
          db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW view_name " +
                     "AS SELECT [...]"
          );
       }
    })
    .build();
```

this way room would let you use the view name in queries and map the retrieved data on your @Entity class correctly,
 although you have to keep in mind that this approach will break the migration. 
for migrations to work you have to find a workaround (maybe drop your view and recreate the fake table might work)